# Block native datepicker to show

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, datebox

I am trying to use the datebox plugin (http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/), to generate some custom datapicker boxes in my jquerymobile app.

I am calling tham using:

```
<input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" data-role="dateBox" data-theme="d" data-options ='{"mode": "flipbox", "focusMode": true ,"useClearButton": true, "centerWindow": true}'
```

My problem is that, if I open the date-box using the the specific button, it opens fine, but if I open pressing the texbox (it should work because I have the focusMode: true) it opens both the datebox and the native datepicker.

I have tried like it is sugested in the jquerymobile docs for the select (date-native-menu: false) but it doesn't work. I also don't know how to use it for the input instead of the select.

On the other hand, if I use the normal popup method (instead of the centerWindow: true), the problem disapears, but I want to use the centered method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you *always* want to use DateBox, you can change the type to "text" - the plugin actually should be doing this for you - I'll try and track down what's different between centerWindow and standard.

Comment: fwiw, I am currently ignoring data-native-menu - although I suppose it wouldn't be a bad idea to do something to specifically respect it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Changing the type to text did help in not showing the native datepicker, but it showed the keyboard instead

Comment: Hmm.  ok, I'll take a closer look - by default, datebox is *supposed* to mark the input readonly, which *should* suppress the keyboard from popping up on focus.

Comment: Also, which version of DateBox is this?  I might be hunting for bugs in the newer incarnation that didn't actually carry over - my guess from "centerWindow" is ver1.